# Adding HTML Tags to an Email Using Code Igniter and SendGrid

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email, sendgrid

I searched Google for a solution but was unable to find anything.

I am using the Code Igniter Framework and SendGrid to do SMTP. My script is as follows:

```
$this->email->initialize(array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    'smtp_user' => 'MY_SENDGRID_USERNAME',
    'smtp_pass' => 'MY_SENDGRID_PASSWORD',
    'smtp_port' => THE_PORT_I_AM_USING,
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'newline' => "\r\n"
));     

$this->email->from('info@gmail.com', 'Info');
$this->email->to("example@example.com");
$this->email->subject("My subject");
$message = "<p>Hello ...</p>
<a href="http://google.com">Click here</a> to go Google.";
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

However when I receive the email, it just contains the HTML as plain text, like such:

```
<p>Hello ...</p>
<a href="http://google.com">Click here</a> to go Google.
```

Answer (score 1):

With [Code Igniter's Email Class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/email.html), which you appear to be using, you must set your `mailtype` to `html` when initializing, otherwise it defaults to `text`. Change your initialize function to:

```
$this->email->initialize(array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    'smtp_user' => 'SENDGRID_USERNAME',
    'smtp_pass' => 'SENDGRID_PASSWORD',
    'smtp_port' => WHATEVER_PORT_YOURE_USING,
    'mailtype' => 'html',
    'crlf' => "\r\n",
    'newline' => "\r\n"
));
```

You'll then be able to send HTML using all your other code.

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of `$message` variable?
Try defining complete HTML (as you normally would, with links you want, eg.: `<a href="your_link">Your link</a>`) in `$message` since it is sent as body (message) of the email.

Answer (score 0):

No need for additional libraries.  Simply add 'mailtype' => 'html' when you initalize

```
    $this->email->initialize(array(
      'protocol' => 'smtp',
      'smtp_host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',   
      'smtp_user' => 'xxxx',
      'smtp_pass' => 'xxxx',
      'smtp_port' => 587,
      'mailtype' => 'html',
      'crlf' => "\r\n",
      'newline' => "\r\n"
    ));
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
$this->load->library('email');

$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';

$this->email->initialize($config);
```